# UWP Deploy Assets from arbitrary path

Tags: visual-studio, uwp

I want to avoid duplicating 400+ files in the Assets folder of my UWP App project folder. I want to tell VS to take files from an arbitrary location in my source tree, and use those in the Assets folder, preserving folder structure etc for deployment. I don't even mind setting the pathing manually in the project file properties if I must.

Is there a way to do this? The best I got was to right click on Assets\BlahFilter -> Add -> Existing Item. This results in the file appearing in the Solution treeview in the place I expect, but when deploying, the file appears in the root of AppX folder, ignoring any subfolder (filter) structure specified above.

Comment: How are you accessing these files? relative path? or `ms-appx`?

Comment: To be clear -- I'm not talking about accessing them at runtime. Deployed files under the Assets folder are accessible just fine by using Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder; to get the local folder root.

I'm talking about wanting to be able to have content be deployed in the AppX Assets folder at compile/deploy time, without having to duplicate them from their current location.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this. You can use a "Custom Build Step" and treat the output as content. This will result in VS packaging that output directory's contents in the final AppX package. You can specify a folder, and all sub-folders will be automatically copied. The build command can be blank, or something innocuous like 'echo "blah"'

[image]